# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Failed to migrate Worklight project

Tags: linux, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

In my Linux machine,

1. when I import the [WorklightStarter project](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/WorklightStarter.zip) for Worklight 6.1 into a brand new Eclipse environment (w/Worklight Studio installed from the Eclipse MarketPlace),  I got the following error and thus the project is not imported:

   > [2014-02-11 12:54:25] FWLPL0026E: Migrating the WorklightStarter
   >   project from version 6.1.0.0 to version 6.1.0.0 has failed
   >   (/tmp/wlBuildResources/6.1.0.00.20131219-1900/environments/versions.properties
   >   (No such file or directory))
2. When I create my own project and try to build it, I get the following error:

   > [2014-02-12 07:22:20] FWLST1037W: Requested to build 'mobilewebapp'
   >   but there is no optimization folder for it.  [2014-02-12 07:22:21]
   >   FWLST1040E: common build failed: Parameter 'directory' is not a
   >   directory [2014-02-12 07:22:21] FWLST1040E: desktopbrowser build
   >   failed: Parameter 'directory' is not a directory [2014-02-12 07:22:22]
   >   Application 'worklightStarter' with all environments build finished.
   >   [2014-02-12 07:22:27]             Parameter 'directory' is not a
   >   directory

---

If I install the plug-in in Eclipse in **Windows** and do the same, it works!

So I think the problem seems to be in **Linux** only? I guess a problem is in a path format somewhere '\' vs '/'? or something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Navigate to your temp directory and delete the wlBuildResources folder. 
Re-build of the project should fix this issue.

Comment: Deleting wlBuildResources is a workaround. A defect was discovered and a ticket was opened for it.

Comment: I got the same issue on a MAC machine and I delete the wlBuildResources folder but this doesn't fix the issue unless I **restarted Eclipse**. After that the problem was revolved. Hope this helps.